# Word MailMerge from Access is not picking up query

Tags: ms-access, ms-word, vba, mailmerge

I am not a VBA programmer. I'm trying to help a friend debug an issue in his Access / VBA app.

When a button is clicked, a function is run which pops up a dialog asking for some parameters; it them builds an SQL query, runs it to check if there are results, and then runs a mailmerge against a word document.

The problem is that when word is opened, it: a) asks which table the merge should use and b) doesn't seem to run the query which is passed to it. My guess is that if I can fix #b, then #a will also be fixed. So, something is likely wrong with this code:

```
objWord.MailMerge.openDataSource _
    Name:=CurrentProject.FullName, _
    ReadOnly:=True, _
    OpenExclusive:=False, _
    LinkToSource:=True, _
    Connection:="TABLE " & TableName, _
    SQLStatement:=query

objWord.MailMerge.Execute
```

Here is the documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841005(v=office.15).aspx

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think its related to wildcard in Query, use % instead of * and use _ instead of ?